# Providing iterable "views" of a class by casting parent class to reference to child

Tags: c++

I have a class, and there are several ways to iterate over it. For example, you can iterate to see all the `A`'s, `B`'s, or `C`'s inside it. The class has no virtual functions.

I want these to have a nice interface. I am wondering if the following gives undefined or unspecified behavior, or if it is OK to do.

I am thinking about making three derived classes of this class:

```
// can look at this in three ways
struct myClass {
    void myFunc();
};

struct A_view : public myClass {
    A_iterator begin();
};

struct B_view : public myClass {
    B_iterator begin();
};


struct C_view : public myClass {
    C_iterator begin();
};
```

Then

```
A_view& get_C_view(const myClass& c) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<B_view*>(&c);
}

B_view& get_B_view(const myClass& c) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<B_view*>(&c);
}

C_view& get_C_view(const myClass& c) {
    return *static_cast<C_view*>(&c);
}
```

I want to be able to do use it like

```
myClass inst;

for (auto& c : get_C_view(inst))
    //stuff

for (auto& b : get_B_view(inst))
    //stuff
```

and

```
auto& bview  = get_b_view(inst);

std::transform(bview.begin(), bview.end(), bview.begin(), [](auto& x, auto& y) { /* smthing */ });

bview.myFunc();
```

or whatever with the algorithms from `<algorithm>`. As you can see, you can also use the functions defined in the parent class on the view.

So, I am casting an instance to a reference to a type that is derived from it which adds only functions, not data, but it is not actually one of those types.

Is this ok? By "ok" I mean

1. Is this well defined, undefined, or unspecified behavior?
2. If not well defined, will this cause problems in practice?
3. Would Herb Sutter frown upon it?

Comment: Why not just have `A_begin`, `A_end`, etc. methods? Or, if you're set on having separate classes for each type, make `A_view` a friend class, not a derived class.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter because there are too many in my actual situation. Also those won't work with things that require `begin`/`end` methods, like range-based for.

Comment: If you simply make `A_view` a standalone class instead of a derived class (like in the answer below), you should be able to use it in the exact same way, and write almost the same number of lines of code. You would only need to make it a friend if the equivalent of `c_begin()` is private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance is not the correct tool to use in this case for multiple reasons, the first is that you cannot cast an object to a type that it is not, but more generally than that because inheritance is the second highest coupling relationship in the language and should be used sparingly (i.e. when needed, not just because).

You can create thin wrapper types that holds a reference to your type and map their begin/end functions to the appropriate views over your component:

```
struct C_view {
   MyClass &obj;
   C_view(MyClass& obj) : obj(obj) {}
   C_iterator begin() {
     return obj.c_begin();
   }
   C_iterator end() {
     return obj.c_end();
   }
};
```

Then user code becomes:

```
for (auto &c : C_view(inst)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: But then you have to have a clunkier way to access functions on the thing being wrapped. So, by the beginning of your answer, is this undefined or unspecified or...?

Comment: @Jay: So you'd rather have undefined behavior than have to type a bit more? That is an option, but your coworkers might not agree with your approach.

Comment: You never said it was undefined, that was my question.

Comment: @Jay: *you **cannot** cast an object to a type that it is not* --> incorrect (do you really mind that much how incorrect it is? well, in this particular case it is undefined behavior)

Comment: Oh, somehow I missed that part. Thanks.

Comment: @Jay: If you are really interested in the gory details, if the derived type does not add any members, then it will probably *work* (i.e. undefined behavior may look like well defined) in most implementations. But it would still be wrong, and there is nothing inhibiting the next compiler version to break your code.